# How to convert a Python file to tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to input nude detection feature for my app using tensorflow lite.

I found a data set that suitable for my integration. But I have zero experience on python and and tensorflow. Now I need to convert [this file](https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/blob/v2/nudenet/classifier.py) into tflite.  I used **colab** as a tool.
and this is what i tried on the tool, But it did not work.

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("classifier.py")
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f: 
f.write(tflite_model)
```

[Reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#python_api)

I need help to convert [this file](https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/blob/v2/nudenet/classifier.py) to tflite

Comment: "*It did not work*" is not much helpful for possible respondents; what *exactly* is the issue you are facing? Please post a [mre].

Comment: classifier.py is not a model, is a python file that loads a model from https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/releases/download/v0/classifier_model.onnx.  this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63442788/9983880 shows how to convert an onnx model to a tensorflowlite model

Comment: @desertnaut , I did not add the error because, I have no experience on python, Even you say how to solve that error, I won't be able solve that. After that I might face more errors. Thats why I wanted to know prefect way to do that from an expert.

Comment: hey, did you find it? i am also search for it.